# How to prevent/report potential mod power abuse?

Tags: discussion, support, comments

On Stackoverflow with it's higher visibility and factual natural, this might not come across often, but on stack exchange for say "interpersonal skills", a lot of non-factual opinions are expressed, so that can cause moderator bias.

For example if you don't like someone's wording on something or believe in certain things, you can remove all opposing comments when they are completely legit. For example, [this issue](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/18103/how-to-tactfully-check-whether-my-new-partner-is-a-man-or-a-woman/18110#18110). Mutiple people pointed out that the correct top two answer aren't useful. It might sound nice to "simply to truthful and respectful and ask", but that's not what the OP is asking and he clearly mentions it (that he doesn't want to risk offending the other person). Even the question is posted as "how to check" not "how to politely ask". All such comments were deleted for some random reason... Why?

Comment: If you have a question about actions taken on a specific question, it's better to ask it on [Interpersonal Skills' own meta site](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/). But please check existing questions there first, they might already contain the answer for that.

Answer (score 20):

If you do not understand why the comments were deleted, you can - and should - ask on the site's Meta. The site's moderators get notified for every new Meta question, I'm sure one of them will answer yours.

That said, do keep in mind that comments are considered third-class citizens on Stack Exchange. They are not supposed to stick around and may be removed at any time, for a variety of reasons. Don't be so quick to yell "mod abuse", especially for something as trivial as comment removal.